# Tinymce PHP CRUD mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce, crud

I'm using Tinymce along with PHP and mysql.

I can get the create, read, and delete working just fine, but the update part is random. For instance, half the time mysql will load the content into the textarea for editing, and about half the time it won't. I just get an empty textarea. It doesn't seem to matter if I type the content in or copy and paste from another source.

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',

    height: 400,

    theme: "modern",

    statusbar: true,

    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview hr table paste textcolor code"
    ],

    toolbar: "undo redo | forecolor backcolor | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | preview"
})
</script>
```

PHP code.

```
<?php 
include_once 'connect_db.php';

$id = null;
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}

if( null == $id){
  header("Location: jobs.php");
}

$required = array("company_name", "city", "state", "job_title", "job_description", "approved", "duration");
$Msg = '';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){

      $company_name     = $_POST['company_name'];
      $city             = $_POST['city'];
      $state            = $_POST['state'];
      $job_title        = $_POST['job_title'];
      $job_description  = $_POST['job_description'];
      $approved         = $_POST['approved'];
      $duration         = $_POST['duration'];

      $valid = true;

      foreach($required as $req){
            if(empty($_POST[$req])){
              $valid = false;
          }
      }

      if(!$valid){
            $Msg = "<p>Error! Empty or invalid input.</p>";
      }

      if($valid){

            $sql = "UPDATE jobs SET company_name= ?, city= ?, state= ?, job_title= ?, job_description= ?, approved= ?, duration= ? WHERE id = ?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array($company_name, $city, $state, $job_title, $job_description, $approved, $duration, $id));
            $conn = null;
            header("Location: jobs.php");
      }

      }else{

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id= ?";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(array($id));
      $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $company_name  = $result['company_name'];
      $city   = $result['city'];
      $state  = $result['state'];
      $job_title  = $result['job_title'];
      $job_description  = $result['job_description'];
      $approved   = $result['approved'];
      $duration = $result['duration'];
      $conn = null;

     }      
?>
```

Comment: Show how your loading the content on update. Without all the code its hard to help.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that would help, too.  Just attached it.